# Querying using multiple LIKEs from same column?

Tags: mysql, sql

My database is listing Jobs. I want a user to be able to query jobs from a particular industry but chose as many work-types from the `type` column as they want, eg:

```
SELECT * FROM `rec_jobs` 
WHERE `industry` LIKE '%Security%' AND 
   (`type` LIKE '%Full-Time%' OR 'type' LIKE '%Part-Time%' OR 'type' LIKE '%Casual%' OR 'type' LIKE '%Contract%');
```

This should return something like:

> **ID - Industy - Type**
>
> ---
>
> 1 - Security - Part-Time
>
> 2 - Security - Full-Time
>
> 3 - Security - Casual
>
> 4 - Security - Full-Time

etc.

but it is not working as expected - I dont get any SQL errors or any results (though I know rows exist).

Does anyone know a better way of achieving this (or the correct terminology to search in Google)?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

you should use the same quotes around the column name type:

```
SELECT *
FROM `rec_jobs`
WHERE `industry` LIKE '%Security%'
    AND (
        `type` LIKE '%Full-Time%'
        OR `type` LIKE '%Part-Time%'
        OR `type` LIKE '%Casual%'
        OR `type` LIKE '%Contract%');
```

Comment: @MeltingDog But like is not nessesary in this case. you can also use `IN` or `equals`

Answer (score 2):

If you know the exact strings you are looking for then use `IN()`

```
SELECT * FROM `rec_jobs` 
WHERE `industry` = 'Security' 
AND `type` IN ('Full-Time', 'Part-Time', 'Casual', 'Contract')
```

Answer (score 2):

You used

```
'type'
```

while it should be

```
`type`
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM rec_jobs 
WHERE type IN ('Full-Time', 'Part-Time', 'Casual', 'Contract')
AND industry`='Security'
```